# How to pre-install 3-party Python package on spark cluster

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a spark cluster, from machine-1 to machine 100, and machine-1 acts as the master.

Then one day my program need use a 3-party python package which is not installed on every machine of the cluster.

so here comes my problem: to make that 3-party python package usable on master and slaves, should I ***manually*** ssh to every machine and use pip to install that package?

I believe there should be some deploy scripts or other things to make this grace, but I can't find anything after googling.

anyway, great thanks.